# Is it possible to use it as a laptop external CD player through USB or AV in AV out?

Tags: dvd, cd

I have a Sylvania DVD/CD player that has a small screen, you can play movies, music from any CD/DVD and SD card/USB on it. Is there any way for me to connect it to a laptop, with the USB male to female cable, or some other way, or use the AV in/AV out to get a CD to show its content on the laptop and copy it to the laptop from the CD like an external CD/DVD player for a laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  The only output on those portable CD/DVD players is the RCA AV out.  You *could* purchase a USB video capture device, connect it to your laptop, then attach the CD/DVD player to that.  However, the video and audio quality on RCA AV out is very low.

You would be ***far*** better off buying an external writable USB BluRay/DVD/CD drive, because you can access the digital contents.  Using CD/DVD ripping software, which you can get for free, you can can create perfect digital copies of the data.  Not to mention the drive will be faster and have more use.

Comment: Would a USB video capture device attached to the DVD player let you copy the contents of the CD to the laptop? Would the USB that's on the DVD player not be able to be used to transfer the contents from the CD with USB male to USB  female cable? Thanks

Comment: The USB port is most likely for reading a thumb drive or so only (i.e. it's a host port)

Comment: @user1302333 the USB on the player is input only.  As mentioned, you *could* buy a capture device, but an external DVD drive for your laptop is the better choice.